# How to prove that $ (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline {B}) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup \overline {B}) = A $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I got stuck trying to prove that
$ (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline {B}) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup \overline {B}) $ and vice versa.

Comment: Please don't use the symbol $\overline{A}$ when you mean the complement of $A$. This symbol usually denotes the closed hull.

Answer (score 4):

Draw it! I have drawn $(A \cap B)$ and $(A \cap \overline {B})$ for you below, then you should be able to see that this is the same as $A$. I find once you can see it, is becomes a lot easier to find a proof for now.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're dealing with set intersection and union, the only thing you can ever really do is translate back to the language of element membership.

I shall prove this triple set equality by proving three subset relations, namely that $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B}) \subseteq A \subseteq (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup \overline{B}) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})$.

**To show the first subset, that $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B}) \subseteq A$**:

Suppose $x\in (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})$.
Then $x\in (A\cap B$ or $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$, and so we have two cases:

Case 1: We assume $x\in A \cap B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. So $x\in A$ as required.

Case 2: we assume $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$ and hence $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. So $x\in A$ as required, and we are done.

**To show the next subset:**
Suppose $x\in A$. Then trivially $x\in A \lor x\in B$, so $x\in A\cup B$. Similarly, $x\in A \lor x \in \overline{B}$, so $x\in A\cup \overline{B}$. Then $x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup \overline{B})$, as required.

**To show the next subset:**

Suppose $x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup \overline{B})$. Then $x \in (A\cup B)$ and $x\in (A\cup \overline{B}$). From the first of these statements, we have that $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and likewise from the second that $x\in A$ or $x\in \overline{B}$. Let us perform cases on the first statement.

Case 1: Suppose $x\in A$. By the law of the excluded middle, either $x\in B$ or $x\in \overline{B}$. So by subcases, we may certainly either construct $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$. Then $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap \overline{B}$, and we are done.

Case 2: Suppose $x\in B$. But this means that $x\not\in \overline{B}$ by the definition of the set complement. Since we also know that $x\in A$ or $x\in \overline{B}$, we may destruct this to find that $x\in A$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ and hence $x\in A\cap B$, so $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap \overline{B})$ as required. Then we are done.

This concludes the proof. 
Since the subsets form a closed circuit, clearly they are all equal.

This was probably more thorough than you needed, as after a point you could probably just get away with using De Morgan's laws, but this is the real barebones set-theoretic proof.

Answer (score 1):

Distributive laws:

Let $A,B \subset X$; $B^c: =X$ \ $B$.

1) $A= A\cap (B \cup B^c) =$

$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$.

2) $A= A\cup (B \cap B^c)=$

$ (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c).$

Note : $B\cup B^c =X;$ $B\cap B^c=\emptyset.$

https://www.easycalculation.com/theorems/distributive-law.php

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the distributive law.

If you don't want to do it with normal set theory laws you could just consider four cases; elements in $A$ and $B$, elements in neither, elements in $A$ but not $B$, and elements in $B$ but not $A$. Checking that the relation holds true for all four cases suffices to prove the statement.

Comment: Have you tried applying De Morgan's Laws?

Answer (score 0):

To prove $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap\bar{B})=A$, write the condition for membership of the left-hand side as $(x\in A\land x\in B)\lor (x\in A\land x\not\in B)$, with $\land$ and, and $\lor$ the inclusive or. This is $x\in A\land (x\in B\lor x\not\in B)$ by distributivity, which is $x\in A\land\top$ by the law of the excluded middle, where $\top$ is a tautology. And of course, this simplifies to $x\in A$. To exchange $\cap,\,\cup$, giving $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup\bar{B})=A$, note duality of $\land,\,\lor$ implies duality of $\cap,\,\cup$, so the same logic applies again.